# Show that $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n + 1}{n+1}$ is decreasing starting from some $n_0$ and find $n_0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, monotone-functions

> Given $n\in \mathbb N$ and: 
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n + 1}{n+1} \\
> x_1 = -10
> \end{cases}
> $$ 
>   Show that $x_n$ is decreasing starting from some index $n_0$. Find $n_0$.

I've tried to find a closed form of the sequence:

$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1}\\
x_n = \frac{x_{n-1}}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\\
x_{n-1} = \frac{x_{n-2}}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n-1}\\
\dots
$$

Now consecutively substituting $x_k$ one may obtain:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_{n-2}\cdot \frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)}
$$

By expanding the pattern we get:

$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{n!}{(n+1)!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)!} +\dots \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + x_1\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)!} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n+1-k)!}{(n+1)!}\right) + \frac{x_1}{(n+1)!}
$$

I couldn't find a closed form for the sum.

I've been also thinking of another way to show that. If we assume that $x_n$ is indeed decreasing starting from some $x_k$ then there should exist a supremum of the sequence and the following should hold:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_k > x_{k-1} \\
x_k > x_{k+1}
\end{cases}
$$

But i'm not sure how to isolate $k$ from that system. I've also tried to play around with the consecutive terms in order to arrive at some linear recurrence and try to find its closed form by utilizing its characteristic polynomial but failed.

Could you please show me how to prove the problem statement and find the required $n_0$

Please note the precalculus tag. Thank you!

Comment: Direct calculations suggest that the sequence maximum is $a_6 = 143/720$.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Indeed. I've also done some rough calculations. However I would like to know whether there exists a "symbolic" approach to the problem rather than a direct computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve

$$\frac{x+1}{n+1}<x,$$ which gives

$$nx>1.$$

Then the first few terms are

$$-10,-\frac92,-\frac76,-\frac1{24},\frac{23}{120},\frac{143}{720}$$ and the last one exceeds $\dfrac1n$.

Comment: Thank you. Where does the first inequality come from? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @roman: that just expresses "decreasing".

Comment: The first inequality merely expresses $a_{n+1} < a_n$.